# Why this CSS3 animation doesn't work in MS Edge or IE11?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgh1xhbq) and below is the CSS code (the HTML is just an SVG ellipse). It works in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but doesn't work in IE and Edge. What to do to see the animation in IE and Edge?

```
#my-circle {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-dasharray: 1100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  -moz-animation: draw-first-shape 1s forwards 3;
  -webkit-animation: draw-first-shape 1s forwards 3;
  animation: draw-first-shape 1s forwards 3;
}

@-moz-keyframes draw-first-shape {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes draw-first-shape {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes draw-first-shape {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason `stroke-dashoffset` animation doesn't work in IE. But if you use `stroke-dasharray` like in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vgh1xhbq/1/) then it would work atleast in Edge. It would still not work in IE11.

Comment: Works great, thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470958/css-transition-doesnt-work-properly-in-chrome/41471277#41471277

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though MSDN says that ***as of MS Edge*** the [stroke-dashoffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property is animatable with CSS animations and transitions, it ***still doesn't work*** for some reason. If we re-create this animation using `stroke-dasharray` instead of `stroke-dashoffset` then it works as expected in Edge.

But it will ***still not work in IE11*** or lower because again as indicated in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972273(v=vs.85).aspx), the `stroke-dasharray` is animatable using CSS animations and transitions only from MS Edge.

The modified animation still works in latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

```css
#my-circle {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-dasharray: 1100;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: draw-first-shape 1s forwards 3;
}
@keyframes draw-first-shape {
  from {
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 1100;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 1100, 1100;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500.00001 300" id="svg2">
  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0 -752.362)">
    <ellipse id="my-circle" cx="257.013" cy="907.735" rx="201.742" ry="111.465" fill="#fff" stroke="#007400" stroke-width="3" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for MS Edge, you can animate `stroke-width` (making a tiny variation of its value) together with `stroke-dashoffset`. For instance, in the case of the question:

```
@keyframes draw-first-shape {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        stroke-width: 3.03;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-width: 3;
    }
}
```